# Archlinux Skype problems with build-in microphone

Tags: skype, archlinux, alsa, pulseaudio

So. My problems with next: I use pulseaudio as a sound server. I check my mic settings by arecord. All ok, but in Skype mic not working. Only silence. But when I tested it with Skype service and look at pavucontrol I saw that mic worked. Please, help!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming or code, and so is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. This belongs on the Unix Stack Exchange (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or the Arch Linux Forums (https://bbs.archlinux.org/).

Answer (score 2):

here is my checklist I look through whenever I have any problems with Skype and pulseaudio:

- open alsamixer and make sure the input source and volume settings are correct
- open pavucontrol and make sure the Input Devices -> Port dropdown  is set to the right value
- make sure Skype itself has detected pulseaudio and is using it as a default device.

hope it helps

Comment: Not useful. Problem is more global.